# No matching function to call to std::swap - std::swap и QCharRef

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Нужно поменять местами последний и предпоследний символы `QString`. Решил делать через `std::swap()`:

```
unsigned recursive_damerau(const QString &s1, const QString &s2)
    {
        if (s1 == "")
            return s2.length();
        if (s2 == "")
            return s1.length();
        const char adder = (s1.back() == s2.back());
        unsigned s1_length = s1.length();
        unsigned min_dist;
        QString s1_short = s1, s2_short = s2;
        s1_short.chop(1);
        s2_short.chop(1);
        min_dist = min(min(recursive_damerau(s1, s2_short) + 1, recursive_damerau(s1_short, s2) + 1), recursive_damerau(s1_short, s2_short) + adder);
        if (s1_length != 1) // As it is also not zero, that means >=2
        {
            QString s1_swapped = s1;
            std::swap(s1_swapped[s1_length - 1], s1_swapped[s1_length - 2]);
            min_dist = min(min_dist, recursive_damerau(s1_swapped, s2));
        }
        return min_dist;
    }
```

Получаю ошибки: [image: Ошибка1][image: Ошибка2]
Насколько я понимаю, это потому что `QString::operator[]` возвращает `QCharRef` вместо `QChar&`, который в данном случае неправильно обрабатывается.
Есть ли способ это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
QString str("Hello world");
str.insert(str.size()-2,str[str.size()-1]).chop(1);
```

Если через стандартную библиотеку, то можно использовать `iter_swap`:

```
std::iter_swap(std::end(str)-1, std::end(str)-2);
```

Comment: Ну, я сделал по-школьному, через дополнительную переменную:  
    `const QChar tmp = s1_swapped[s1_length - 1];  
     s1_swapped[s1_length - 1] = s1_swapped[s1_length - 2];  
     s1_swapped[s1_length - 2] = tmp;`  
Думаю, это работает быстрее. Но вопрос в том, что произошло, и как исправить. Я бы, все же, предпочел std::swap

Comment: Получилось через `iter_swap`